# Magento2: wrong config data value per store

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get some Magento2 custom core_config_data values, as explained in other topics, but I have some wrong values related to the store IDs. I will try to explain, let's start with some relevant code:

```
public function __construct(
  \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
  \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {..}

  {
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
    $this->logger->debug($store->getId() . ": " . $store->getCode());
    $message = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONF_MESSAGE,
      \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $link = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONF_LINK,
      \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

What happens here is that the **store ID** and the **store code** are **correct**.
In the logs I see

```
main.DEBUG: 3: tedesco
```

The values I got in `$message` and `$link` are **not correct**: they are the values of another store (the correct store ID should be 3 as shown from the debug log, but the value is the one from the store with ID 1).

Of course I have checked the DB and the values are just fine as shown in the picture: [image: DB values].

Magento 2.1.4.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you pass store or store id to 3rd param?

```
$message = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONF_MESSAGE,
  \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
```

Comment: thank you very much, the $store (`$store = $this->storeManager->getStore();`) was the parameter I had to pass.

Comment: You're welcome, but I've been assuming that if you don't pass 3rd parameter it has to get a current store by default.

Comment: And I was assuming that using `SCOPE_STORE` was a way to say "scope is store, so use the current store". I was so sure that I didn't go to check the `getValue()` function code, and that was a big mistake...thanks again